# String array to DataGridView

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datagridview

I'm using this code when I try to add data from string arrays to `DataGridView`.

```
string fileDataField[];
count = fileDataField.Count();
count = count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
     DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnDataGridTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
     columnDataGridTextBox.Name = fileDataField[i];
     columnDataGridTextBox.HeaderText = fileDataField[i];
     columnDataGridTextBox.Width = 120;
     dataGridView2.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox);
}
dataGridView2.Rows.Add(fileDataField);
```

But first row becomes header. But I don't want to load items to first and last rows.

Comment: you have to show more of your code

Comment: True, I realized it. Sorry.

Comment: edit your question, adding the code, or if you start a new one, delete this one, or flag it yourself as to be closed because of a duplicate, and then you can link to the new question, please. :-)

Comment: I re-answered the post. You can check it.

Comment: I edited your question properly. Now please delete the answer @Alptekinİpek

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow, sorry.

Comment: don;t worry.. that is totally ok. even if some comments may sound hard, it is not meant badly.. it is just people in their efficient, programming mode (not realizing they deal with beings with feelings). most new users do not even try to follow advice, or do so badly... you are an exceptionally good beginner. keep on! :-)

Comment: @Alptekinİpek What u want exactly.. Did not get your question..If you dont want your String arrary to apper in the header then Just dont add `Headertext`

Comment: Even ı don't add it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alptekinİpek What You what Exactly??!!

Comment: @Alptekinİpek remove this line from loop, columnDataGridTextBox.HeaderText = fileDataField[i];

Answer (score 2):

Dont sure what You want but the below code will not add your `string array` to the Header

```
string[] fileDataField= new string[]{"Mon","Thu","Wed","yh","Friday","sat","Sun","COOL"};
                 int  count = fileDataField.Count();
                 count = count - 1;
              for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
              {
                  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn columnDataGridTextBox = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                  columnDataGridTextBox.Width = 100;
                  dataGridView2.Columns.Add(columnDataGridTextBox);
                 }
                  dataGridView2.Rows.Add(fileDataField);
```

O/P

[image]